# Polymorphic constructor.name property access

Tags: javascript

Given the JavaScript code:

```
function Parent() { ... }
function Child() { ... }

Child.prototype = new Parent();

// toString implementation on the parent object
Parent.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.constructor.name;
}

// And the code:
alert(new Child());
```

... will output "Parent" when the wanted outcome is to get the "Child" string back (the `constructor.name` inside the parent `toString` implementation should return the child constructor name).

Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor, `constructor`: _Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype_.  So its doing exactly what it should be doing, you're looking for alternate functionality (something other than `constructor`).  There are plenty of articles to emulate classical style sub-classing if that's what you're looking for, or you can also go the simpler parasitic inheritance route.

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistencies that you see in the code result is caused by two reasons.first of all if you check Child prototype object with `Object.getPrototypeOf(Child)` you get `function Empty(){}` , so to correct prototype object assignation you should use `Child.__proto__ = new Parent()` instead of `Child.prototype = new Parent();`.second of all its the matter of **prototype chain**.if you see the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf(Child)` after the new assignation, you get `[object Object]`(*in case you haven't defined Parent prototype toString() method. if you have, then it returns Parent(Child prototype) prototype toString() method*) which means that Child has an **object** in its prototype attribute.then you have three choices:

1.assign a toString() method to Child Object itself:

```
Child.toString = function(){ return this.name }
```

in this case you shouldn't use `this.constructor.name` because after prototype assignation its constructor has changed to **Parent**.

2.define Child prototype(Parent) toString() method:

```
Child.__proto__.toString = function(){ return this.name }
```

3.define Child prototype->prototype(Object) toString() method:(*override*)

```
Parent.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.name }
```

**Some Observations:**

1.the reason that I used `__proto__` for assignation at the beginning was that I wanted to access the original prototype property of the object's constructor function and change it.

2.I've used `return this.name` because these methods will be called from Child,so it refrences Child Object.

3.The reason that I used `__proto__` in **option 2** and `prototype` in **option 3** is that we use `__proto__` when the Object constructor has changed, and `prototype` when the Object constructor hasn't changed.

4.to test the `toString()` method you should use `alert(Child)` rather that `alert(new Child())`.

Here is an article that helps you a lot about prototypes:

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

All aspects of this answer is tested with Chrome JS Console.